# How to parse a CSV to a multidimensional array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I have a CSV file with the following content:

```
Date,Transaction details,Debit,Credit
January 03 2014,POS transaction,"36,80",
,Card No: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx,,
,Terminal: AUCHAN ROMANIA SA  RO  CLUJ NAPOCA,,
,Date: 02-01-2014 AuthID: 382542,,
January 03 2014,POS transaction,"116,69",
,Card No: xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx,,
,Terminal: AUCHAN ROMANIA SA  RO  CLUJ NAPOCA,,
,Date: 02-01-2014 AuthID: 374829,,
December 31 2013,Fees and taxes,"1,00",
,Monthly SMS alerts service fee: 1,,
```

I'm trying to create an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => January 03 2014
            [Transaction details] => POS transaction
            [Debit] => 36,80
            [Credit] =>
            [Card No.] => Card No: xxxx xxxx xxxx 2113
            [Notes] => Terminal: AUCHAN ROMANIA SA  RO  CLUJ NAPOCA
            [Date and AuthID] => Date: 02-01-2014 AuthID: 382542
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => January 03 2014
            [Transaction details] => POS Transaction
            [Debit] => 116,69
            [Credit] =>
            [Card No.] => Card No: xxxx xxxx xxxx 2113
            [Notes] => Terminal: AUCHAN ROMANIA SA  RO  CLUJ NAPOCA
            [Date and AuthID] => Date: 02-01-2014 AuthID: 374829
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => January 03 2014
            [Transaction details] => Fees and taxes
            [Debit] => 1,00
            [Credit] =>
            [Card No.] =>
            [Notes] => Monthly SMS alerts service fee
            [Date and AuthID] =>
        )
)
```

I'm particulary interested in keeping the *Notes* field, becasuse I will later use that field for categorising the transactions.

I appreciate any help.

**EDIT:** I figured out myself too how to parse a CSV into an array, but I wasn't able to figure out how to merge one or multiple rows into an array within the array. Perhaps my problem wasn't described clearly enough.

Curently this is the array that is being returned:

```
array(258) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Data"]=>
    string(16) "January 03 2014"
    ["Detalii tranzactie"]=>
    string(13) "POS transaction"
    ["Debit"]=>
    string(5) "36,80"
    ["Credit"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Data"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Detalii tranzactie"]=>
    string(29) "Nr. card: xxxx xxxx xxxx 2113"
    ["Debit"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Credit"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [2]=>
  array(4) {
    ["Data"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Detalii tranzactie"]=>
    string(44) "Terminal: AUCHAN ROMANIA SA  RO  CLUJ NAPOCA"
    ["Debit"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["Credit"]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php. See comments.

Answer (score 1):

In your php file which renders the data to CSV file, use `foreach` to loop through the multidimensional array.

Say, your array is called as `$csv_array`. Then loop through this array like:

```
foreach($csv_array as $csv_data1)
{
  foreach($csv_data1 as $data)
  {
    echo "\"".$data."\"".",";  
  }
 echo "\n";
}
```

This will render the data correctly for multidimentional array.

***This is basic idea for retrieving data in csv file, you can test with your array depending upon dimensions.***

Comment: As I mentioned in the edit: I was able to figure out this myself too, but I wasn't able to figure out how merge a specific row into an array field.

Answer (score 0):

```
$rows = array_map('str_getcsv', file('myfile.csv'));
$header = array_shift($rows);
$csv = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
  $csv[] = array_combine($header, $row);
}
```